# How to create the top panel similar to what we see in ScriptLab code task pane?

Tags: office365, office-js, scriptlab

In ScriptLab, the Code task pane has these buttons on top(I guess they are Menu, Info, Run, Delete, etc).
I want to create a task pane similar to this. Can someone help me on how to do this?
After installing ScriptLab, I click on ScriptLab and then "Code" button on ribbon. The "Code" task pane opens up. You see a panel/menu bar on top. I want to know how to create that bar.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site to help answer your questions, not write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

SL uses [Office UI fabric](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric), that specific item its known as an overflow set.  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/overflowset